# Несколько табов на странице

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят помогите пожалуйста. [codepen](https://codepen.io/brezze/pen/yPmvRv)

На странице будет много таких табов, мне нужно что-бы если я кликал на вкладки нижнего таба, в верхнем не убирался класс current и текст оставался всегда видимым. Как этого достичь ?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
  })

})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->

<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-5">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-6">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-7">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-8">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function() {
  
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab'),
        $container = $(this).parent().parent(); 
        //Цепляемся за контейнер-папу текущих табов (div.container)
        // и дальше действуем в нём
        $container.find('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current'); 
        $container.find('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#" + tab_id).addClass('current');
    
    })

})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 100px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', serif;
  line-height: 1.6
}

.container {
  width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

ul.tabs {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
}

ul.tabs li {
  background: none;
  color: #222;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

ul.tabs li.current {
  background: #ededed;
  color: #222;
}

.tab-content {
  display: none;
  background: #ededed;
  padding: 15px;
}

.tab-content.current {
  display: inherit;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-1">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-2">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-3">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-4">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-3" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-4" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->

<div class="container">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab-link current" data-tab="tab-5">Tab One</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-6">Tab Two</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-7">Tab Three</li>
    <li class="tab-link" data-tab="tab-8">Tab Four</li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tab-5" class="tab-content current">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-6" class="tab-content">
    Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-7" class="tab-content">
    Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.
  </div>
  <div id="tab-8" class="tab-content">
    Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>

</div>
<!-- container -->
```